# How to put these Array Response in a table or echo it?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have this Array response, I am pretty new to PHP and Curl. I want this Tracking details such as Status Time, Status Body and Location to put in a table or so. I tried my best but couldn't put it in a table or even echo the following data. I tried using the foreach but didn't know how to properly do it. Please provide the best solution for this :) Thanks

```
    (
[info] => Array
    (
        [courier_name] => delhivery
        [to_pincode] => 226020
        [from_pincode] => 587122
        [to_city] => LUCKNOW
        [from_city] => HUBLI
        [cod_amount] => 0
    )

[track_arr] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [status_array] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 10 Feb 2021, 16:34
                                [status_body] => Shipment picked up
                                [status_location] => Mudhol_ManturRD_D (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 10 Feb 2021, 20:24
                                [status_body] => Shipment Recieved at Origin Center
                                [status_location] => Mudhol_ManturRD_D (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 10 Feb 2021, 20:25
                                [status_body] => Added to Bag
                                [status_location] => Mudhol_ManturRD_D (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 11 Feb 2021, 08:58
                                [status_body] => Bag Added To Trip
                                [status_location] => Mudhol_ManturRD_D (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 11 Feb 2021, 12:08
                                [status_body] => Trip Arrived
                                [status_location] => Bijapur_Jamakhandi_I (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 11 Feb 2021, 12:14
                                [status_body] => Bag Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Bijapur_Jamakhandi_I (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 11 Feb 2021, 13:07
                                [status_body] => Shipment Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Bijapur_Jamakhandi_I (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 11 Feb 2021, 13:33
                                [status_body] => Added to Bag
                                [status_location] => Bijapur_Jamakhandi_I (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 12 Feb 2021, 01:41
                                [status_body] => Bag Added To Trip
                                [status_location] => Bijapur_Jamakhandi_I (Karnataka)
                            )

                        [9] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 12 Feb 2021, 11:46
                                [status_body] => Trip Arrived
                                [status_location] => Kolhapur_Central_H_2 (Maharashtra)
                            )

                        [10] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 12 Feb 2021, 11:52
                                [status_body] => Bag Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Kolhapur_Central_H_2 (Maharashtra)
                            )

                        [11] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 12 Feb 2021, 12:11
                                [status_body] => Shipment Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Kolhapur_Central_H_2 (Maharashtra)
                            )

                        [12] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 12 Feb 2021, 12:12
                                [status_body] => Added to Bag
                                [status_location] => Kolhapur_Central_H_2 (Maharashtra)
                            )

                        [13] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 12 Feb 2021, 15:06
                                [status_body] => Bag Added To Trip
                                [status_location] => Kolhapur_Central_H_2 (Maharashtra)
                            )

                        [14] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 08:51
                                [status_body] => Trip Arrived
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Tauru_GW (Haryana)
                            )

                        [15] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 11:18
                                [status_body] => Bag Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Tauru_GW (Haryana)
                            )

                        [16] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 12:38
                                [status_body] => Bag Added To Trip
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Tauru_GW (Haryana)
                            )

                        [17] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 14:06
                                [status_body] => Trip Arrived
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_HB (Haryana)
                            )

                        [18] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 14:14
                                [status_body] => Received At Delhivery Hub
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_P (Haryana)
                            )

                        [19] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 14:14
                                [status_body] => Bag Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_HB (Haryana)
                            )

                        [20] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 14:42
                                [status_body] => Shipment Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_P (Haryana)
                            )

                        [21] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 15:15
                                [status_body] => Added to Bag
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_P (Haryana)
                            )

                        [22] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 15:15
                                [status_body] => System weight captured
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_P (Haryana)
                            )

                        [23] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 15:15
                                [status_body] => Received At Delhivery Hub
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_HB (Haryana)
                            )

                        [24] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 15:23
                                [status_body] => Bag Added To Trip
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Bilaspur_HB (Haryana)
                            )

                        [25] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 16:06
                                [status_body] => Trip Arrived
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Tauru_GW (Haryana)
                            )

                        [26] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 17:03
                                [status_body] => Bag Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Tauru_GW (Haryana)
                            )

                        [27] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 14 Feb 2021, 23:34
                                [status_body] => Bag Added To Trip
                                [status_location] => Gurgaon_Tauru_GW (Haryana)
                            )

                        [28] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 15 Feb 2021, 14:28
                                [status_body] => Trip Arrived
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Memaura_H (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [29] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 15 Feb 2021, 16:13
                                [status_body] => Bag Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Memaura_H (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [30] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 15 Feb 2021, 20:52
                                [status_body] => Shipment Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Memaura_H (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [31] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 15 Feb 2021, 20:55
                                [status_body] => Added to Bag
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Memaura_H (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [32] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 03:10
                                [status_body] => Bag Added To Trip
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Memaura_H (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [33] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 07:06
                                [status_body] => Trip Arrived
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Aliganj (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [34] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 07:12
                                [status_body] => Bag Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Aliganj (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [35] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 07:45
                                [status_body] => Shipment Received at Facility
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Aliganj (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                    )

                [status_name] => OT
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [status_array] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 08:42
                                [status_body] => Out for delivery
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Aliganj (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 12:36
                                [status_body] => Call placed to consignee
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Aliganj (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                    )

                [status_name] => OO
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [status_array] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 12:37
                                [status_body] => Delivered to consignee - OTP Verified delivery
                                [status_location] => Lucknow_Aliganj (Uttar Pradesh)
                            )

                    )

                [status_name] => DL
            )

    )

[edd_stamp] => 16 Feb 2021, 23:59
[err] => 
[web_address] => 
[auth_token] => 
[client_order_id] => 1720402027
[status] => Array
    (
        [received_by] => 
        [current_status_type] => DL
        [current_status_body] => Your Order has been successfully Delivered
        [current_status_location] => Lucknow_Aliganj (Uttar Pradesh)
        [current_status_time] => 16 Feb 2021, 12:37
    )

[company_name] => 
[tracking_id] => 782372067934
[courier_used] => Delhivery
[logo] => 
[courier_tracking_id] => 782372067934
[order_type] => forward
```

)

Comment: Start with the basics, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
// assuming $response is array of data
$data = $response["track_arr"];
$output = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
    foreach($item["status_array"] as $status) {
        $output[] = [
            "name" => $item["status_name"],
            "time" => $status["status_time"],
            "body" => $status["status_body"],
            "location" => $status["status_location"]
        ];
    }
}
// to check array
// var_dump($output);
// https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- to display collected data in table -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Body</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
        <?php foreach($result as $item): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['time']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['body']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item['location']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much, It helped a lot. There was a mistake at the end where u had to put output instead of result in the foreach part